# Matrix modification with constraint on it

Tags: matrix, constraint

$q$ is a real antisymmetric matrix and can be defined as:

```
Format[q[a_, b_]] := Subscript[q, Row@{a, b}]
q[a_, a_] := 0;
q[a_, b_] := -q[b, a] /; (a > b)
qMat = Array[q, {d, d}]
```

Is there a way to modify the above matrix $q$ of dimension $d$  with constraints on the indices given by:

$$d\longrightarrow dimension$$

$i,j $ are indices
$$p=d/2$$
$$s=0,1$$
$$q_{i+ps,j+ps+d}=\begin{cases}
-b & j\neq i,\\
c & j=i\\
\end{cases}$$

$b,c,l$ are constants.

Comment: is `d` symbolic or an explicit integer? also i'm guessing it's necessarily even? also, how are you using $j+ps+d$ as an index? wouldn't that be out of bounds?

Comment: @thorimur integer